# thmbox: text on the same line as the word theorem

Tags: titles, thmbox

I'm trying to change the style of thmbox's theorems so the text can start on the same line as the title, while keeping the straight line on the left.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmbox}
\newtheorem[M,nocut,nounderline,leftmargin=0cm]{thm}{Th\'eor\`eme}%[section]
\newtheorem[S,nounderline,bodystyle=\noindent,leftmargin=0cm]{exercice}[thm]{Exercice}%[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{exercice}
This is an exercice. It doesn't look like I want it to.
\end{exercice}
\end{document}
```

[image: Exos]

The documentation for thmbox is very short, but it doesn't say how to do this.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `thmbox`?

Comment: @UdiFogiel No, it's just what I have been using until now. If you have another theorem package I can use to do that easily, I'm willing to switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to disable `thmbox`'s redefinition of `\newtheorem` as `\newboxtheorem` with the `nothm` package option, then use its built-in `leftbar` environment to define a new command `\newleftbarthm` that defines a new theorem with a bar on the left. Note the loading of `amsthm` to define a new theorem style with a colon as in your image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}
\usepackage[nothm]{thmbox}

\newboxtheorem[M,nocut,nounderline,leftmargin=0cm]{thm}{Th\'eor\`eme}%[section]

\newtheoremstyle{colon}%
{} % space above
{} % space below
{} % body font
{} % indent
{\bfseries} % head font
{:} % head punctuation
{ } % space after head
{} % theorem head spec

\NewDocumentCommand{\newleftbarthm}{m O{} m}{
    \newtheorem{#1-tmp}[#2]{#3}
    \newenvironment{#1}[1][]{
        \begin{leftbar}[leftmargin=-\parskip]
        \vspace{-1.5ex}
        \begin{#1-tmp}[##1]
        }
        {\end{#1-tmp}
        \vspace{-2.5ex}
        \end{leftbar}
        }}

\theoremstyle{colon}
\newleftbarthm{exercice}[thm]{Exercice}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[a heading]
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{thm}

\begin{exercice}
\lipsum[1][3-6]
\end{exercice}

\begin{exercice}[a heading]
\lipsum[1][7-9]
\end{exercice}

\begin{thm}
\lipsum[2][1-5]
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Feel free to adjust the values for `\vspace`'s in the definition of `\newleftbarthm`, I just guessed.